# Plus / minus icon on accordion on the left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am beginner web developer. I have this code (Bootstrap 4):

```
<section class="product-description pt-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
                    <div class="card mb-0">
                        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
                            <a class="card-title">Opis produktu</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="card-body collapse py-3" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="col-8 px-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
                                terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                             href="#collapseTwo">
                            <a class="card-title">Konserwacja</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseTwo" class="card-body collapse py-3" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="col-8 px-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
                                terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion"
                             href="#collapseThree">
                            <a class="card-title">Inna zakładka</a>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="card-body collapse py-3" data-parent="#accordion">
                            <div class="col-8 px-0">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
                                terry richardson ad
                                squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck
                                quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it
                                squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica,
                                craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur
                                butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth
                                nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This code work fine.
I would like to move the +/- icon from left to right.
How can I do this?

Pastebin: https://pastebin.com/JNTkxt5P

Please help me. I have problem only with site my icon.

Comment: Hi! :) you can use `float-right` class on the icon. But I copied and tried your code. Where is the icon? :/

Comment: Look here: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/produkt.html (live prview)

Comment: Ok, but the icons are already in the right side. Do you want it to the left? If so, then add `float: left` to the `.accordion .card-header.collapsed:after` class.

Comment: thank you, but it's not. working: http://serwer1356363.home.pl/_nauka/produkt.html (please open and close)

Comment: You have `float: right` property set at `.accordion .card-header:after` class. You can change it to `float: left` and let me know if that works.